# How to count the amount of digits per line and then print the line with the most digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file with about 50000 lines and each line has a random string. How can I find the line that contains the most digits?

This is my code:

```
strings = []
with open('account_ids.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        digits_in_line = 0
        for x in line:
            if x.isdigit():
                digits_in_line += 1
```

I just don't know how to find the line with the most digits in it

I only tried this because I don't know what I have to do find the line with the most digits

Comment: You already know how to determine the number of digits in a line; you just need to remember the line with the most digits.  If you knew the line with the most digits read from `f` so far, how would you tell if the current line has even more?

Comment: You need to be storing a ```most_digits``` value.  Start this value at 0 and then for each line, once you get ```digits_in_line```, if it is greater than ```most_digits```, update ```most_digits```, you can also store the line/line number every time you do this update.

Answer (score 0):

I left a comment on the original post but I'll write a few lines of code to show you what I'm talking about

```
strings = []
most_digits = 0 # holds max/most digits 
line_num = 0 # tracks current line
most_digits_line_num = 0 # tracks line with most digits

with open('account_ids.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        digits_in_line = 0
        for x in line:
            if x.isdigit():
                digits_in_line += 1
        if digits_in_line > most_digits: # if digits in current line is greater than previous max, update max and max line num
            most_digits = digits_in_line
            most_digits_line_num = line_num
        line_num += 1 # increment line num after processing line
```

Comment: Note, if there is more than one line with the same number of digits, and they happen to contain the most digits, this code snippet will only grab the first.  You can modify it from here or post a comment clarifying if this is/isn't the behavior you want and I can provide some insight.

Comment: You could use `digits_in_line = sum(c.isdigit() for c in line)`

Comment: @user19077881 you definitely could, I was just adding lines to the OP's existing code